# public key or private key as a password of connect to remote database, ssh

Tags: java, ssh, remote-access, portforwarding

I have a .ppk file which contain public key and private key, I want to make a connection to the remote database ssh( in my java program) , but I don't know, for this connection, I have to use public key as password or private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found my answer, 
for my connection , firstly I made a public and private key for the server(server A) that has my java code,  with this command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

this command generate public and private key. 
and then I put my public key in the server which has my database(server B), in the .ssh folder (/home/user/.ssh)

so I connected to the database with the ssh

```
>ssh  username@ip
```

and finally I put my private key in my java-code which helped me to connect to the database server(server B) from code-server(server A)

this links is helpful:

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html ,

https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews

Answer (score 1):

The public key ist deployed on the server and when you log in, your private Key is used for authentication. This private Key is never transferred via the wire though. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#ARCHITECTURE.

A Password is only needed for your access to the Key via a passphrase.